# How to position the default blender cube given coordinates, direction Z vector and direction Y vector using python?

Tags: python, import, coordinates, axis, vector

New to blender and python here,

Given the following:

Coordinates (X,Y,Z) = (-100,100,1000) and Direction Z vector = (1,0,0) and Direction Y vector = (0,0,-1) where angle between direction vectors is 90 deg

How would I position the default cube in blender there using python?

Comment: It is a little hard to understand the expected workflow here, could you add a little more detail ?

Comment: Wondering if it is possible to have an add on in blender which will load sources using the above list array into correct positions and rotations like lighttools software.

Comment: Ok so you have a csv or excel file with transforms data, and you want to map these values to light objects transforms inside blender, is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: The excel doc produces a txt doc with the coordinates and direction vectors as shown in the example, can blender take this data?

Comment: Please use text to explain the data rather than image.   Blender uses python.  See https://stackoverflow.com (or other python sites, or search here for "[python] csv") re how to import csv or excel etc.    Yes it is possible to make an addon. Suggest edit the question with the python to read the data. (or not)  Add an example of one empty placed to match data line. As the question stands at the moment, to answer (other than _"yes it's doable"_) requires teaching file I/O as well as the blender part. Please consider condensing question to just the how to position empty from data ..

Comment: which if I understand correctly is make a 3 x 3 rotation matrix with X, Y and Z axis as columns. The X axis is Y.cross(Z).  Make the matrix a 4x4 and set its translation to coordinate.

Comment: From this output:
X Y Z L M N P Q R
-500 200 1000 1 -0.1 0 -0.2 -0.3 -1

Data above means:
Coordinates (X,Y,Z) = (-500,200,1000) and Direction Z vector (L,M,N) = (1,-0.1,0) and Direction Y vector (P,Q,R) = (-0.2,-0.3,-1)

How would I for example position the default cube there?

Comment: Yes I read the image. Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/176049/edit) question with these details.  The angle between two direction vectors is around 100 degrees.  (expect axes to be orthongonal (90 degrees))   Please also edit in an example of expected output.

Comment: I'll change the question as to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a 3 x 3 rotation matrix with X, Y and Z axis as columns. Blender matrices are in rows, so will transpose rows to columns. The X axis is Y.cross(Z).

Make the matrix a 4x4 transform matrix and set its translation to coordinate

Note Added a scale factor so location 1000 -> 10. To avoid clipping. Set to 1 or remove.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

context = bpy.context
scale = 0.01 # 1000 is a long way away

x, y, z, l, m, n, p, q, r = -500, 200, 1000, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1

y_axis = Vector((l, m, n)).normalized()
z_axis = Vector((p, q, r)).normalized()

x_axis = y_axis.cross(z_axis).normalized()

M = Matrix((x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)).transposed()

M = M.to_4x4()

M.translation = scale * Vector((x, y, z))

#test
print(M)
print(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)
bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
mt = context.object
mt.empty_display_type = 'ARROWS'
mt.matrix_world = M
```

or to  add a cube

```
#test
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
cube = context.object
cube.matrix_world = M
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @batFINGER, just wondering how I would go about running this correctly? New to this software.

Comment: Paste into empty text in text editor. Click the run script button [>]

Comment: If I wanted an object, say the cube for example to be at this specific position but it does not start from the origin, how would I get this to happen?