# How to get normal of the edge

Tags: python, scripting, edges, normals, bmesh

In the Blender api, it is possible to get the normal of the vertex and face, but it is not possible to get the normal of the edge. Is there any formula for calculating normal of the edge or some other way to get normal?

Comment: In this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/177331/15543 I've estimated "edge normal" by averaging connected face normals. (Could have estimated via edges vertex normal instead.)  The result for boundary edges will vary the most using aforementioned methods.